# Cannot get array length and elements

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have object array in React. My problem is that I cannot take elements or length of the array.
Here is a picture of it in console:

[image: consoled array and its length]

I think data.length should take the length of the array, no?

I print it just like that:

```
  console.log('array length:', searchResult.length);
  console.log('array:', searchResult);
```

How is it possible that I get correct array but wrong length?
My final goal is to display array elements in paragraphs so I need to have length as well as each of the elements value.

This is how I create my array:

```
 fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(post => {
      const result = post.results;
      for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index += 1) {
        const obj = {
          title: result[index].title,
          rating: result[index].vote_average,
          year: result[index].release_date.substr(0, 4),
        };

        tempArray.push(obj);
      }
    })
```

after fetching is over I set react state:
     setSearchResult(tempArray);

UPDATE:
I solved my problem by eliminating for loop. I put the result in react state as soon as I retrieve it. Like that:

```
   fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(post => setSearchResult(post.results))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

setSearchResult is react state that I define previously:

```
 const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
```

And now it can get the length of my searchResult array by doing:

```
 searchResult.length;
```

Comment: just out of curiousity .. will `console.log(data[0])` output the first object ?

Comment: No, its undefined

Comment: well that's weird, can you plase post the output of `JSON.stringify(data)` ?

Comment: that results in just two brackets: []

Comment: @Taki I added a code to demonstrate how I get my array

Comment: are you doing `console.log` after the `fetch` ?

Comment: No. I put the result into a react state and then give the array to other React component. But the thing is that I have the array. It comes. I just cannot take elements of it

Comment: This is because you're logging in the console before the data resolves. In dev tools you can see that `array: []` is an empty array, but when you open it to see its contents the browser has the updated content. Really you're just logging the array before you have it in the code, but chrome devtools is giving you some confusing feedback. Out of interest, can you explain a little more as to why you need the length in order to put the content in paragraphs?

Comment: Why are you not using Array.map ? Why do you have to do this non confirmmistic process? for loop is used in rare cases in functional programing.

Comment: I am glad that i have found a solution. I added it to my question as an update. I think @gaditzkhori is right. For loop was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

since your data is inside an array as an objcet i,e in key value pairs, you can caluculate the length of keys.

In your case you can use like `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: That give just zero (0)